# how to delete using checkbox in asp repeater control with button?

Tags: c#, asp.net

hi can some one help me please. My objective is to allow users to delete multiple rows in the data base called 'messages'.

By selecting the checkboxes user will be able to delete multiple rows after pressing the button.

However nothing happen when i use the codes below. Can some one help me see if there is anything wrong with my codes? Thanks =)

source code

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MainMasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Messages.aspx.cs" Inherits="Messages" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Data" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Data.SqlClient" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">

<SCRIPT runat="server">
private void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    String userLog = Session["loginuser"].ToString();
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        LoadData();


    }
}
public void LoadData()
{
String userLog = Session["loginuser"].ToString();
SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Messages WHERE receiver = '" + userLog + "'",
    "server=19-20\\sqlexpress;database=mpsip;Integrated Security=SSPI");
DataTable table = new DataTable();
adapter.Fill(table);
Repeater1.DataSource = table;
Repeater1.DataBind();

PagedDataSource pds = new PagedDataSource();
pds.DataSource = table.DefaultView;
pds.AllowPaging = true;
pds.PageSize = 10;

int currentPage;

if (Request.QueryString["page"] != null)
{
    currentPage = Int32.Parse(Request.QueryString["page"]);
}
else
{
    currentPage = 1;
}

pds.CurrentPageIndex = currentPage - 1;
Label1.Text = "Page " + currentPage + " of " + pds.PageCount;

if (!pds.IsFirstPage)
{
    linkPrev.NavigateUrl = Request.CurrentExecutionFilePath + "?page=" + (currentPage - 1);
}

if (!pds.IsLastPage)
{
    linkNext.NavigateUrl = Request.CurrentExecutionFilePath + "?page=" + (currentPage + 1);
}

Repeater1.DataSource = pds;
Repeater1.DataBind();
```

}

```
    &nbsp;<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">

            <itemtemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" />
          <b><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "title") %></b>

          <br>From UserID: <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, 
                  "mlogin", "{0:d}") %>
              <br />
              Date: <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, 
                  "dateandtime", "{0:d}") %>
              <br />
              MessageID: <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, 
                  "messageID", "{0:d}") %>
                  <br />


       </itemtemplate>
       <separatortemplate>
          <hr>
       </separatortemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>




        <br />
        <asp:HyperLink ID="linkPrev" runat="server">Previous Page</asp:HyperLink>&nbsp;
        <asp:HyperLink ID="linkNext" runat="server">Next Page</asp:HyperLink>

    <br />
    <asp:Button ID="Button7" runat="server" onclick="Button7_Click" 
    Text="Button" />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />

    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server"></asp:Label>
    <br />
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click" 
        Text="Compose Message" />
    <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" onclick="Button2_Click" 
        Text="Sent Messages" />

</div>
```

```
   protected void Button7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=19-20\\sqlexpress;" + "Initial Catalog = mpsip; Integrated Security = SSPI"))
    {
        conn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmdDel = conn.CreateCommand();
        SqlTransaction transaction = conn.BeginTransaction("MyTransaction");
        cmdDel.Connection = conn;
        cmdDel.Transaction = transaction;
        try
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < Repeater1.Items.Count; i++)
            {
                //This assumes data type of messageID is integer, change (int) to the right type
                cmdDel.CommandText = "delete from messages where messageID = '" + ((String)((DataRow)Repeater1.Items[i].DataItem)["messageID"]) + "'";
                cmdDel.ExecuteNonQuery();

                // Continue your code here

            }
            transaction.Commit();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            try
            {
                transaction.Rollback();
            }
            catch (Exception ex1)
            {
                //TODO: write log
            }
        }
    }


}
```

}

Comment: Add .propertyName of the DataItem (i.e. ((Messages)Repeater1.Items[i].DataItem).messageID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
protected void Button7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bool BindNeeded = false;

    SqlConnection connDelete = new SqlConnection("Data Source=19-20\\sqlexpress;" + "Initial Catalog = mpsip; Integrated Security = SSPI");
    connDelete.Open();
    String mySQL;


    try
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < Repeater1.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            CheckBox CheckBox1 = (CheckBox)
            Repeater1.Items[i].FindControl("CheckBox1");
            if (((CheckBox)Repeater1.Items[i].FindControl("CheckBox1")).Checked)
            {

                //This assumes data type of messageID is integer, change (int) to the right type
                CheckBox CheckBox = (CheckBox)Repeater1.Items[i].FindControl("CheckBox1");
                Literal litMessageId = (Literal)Repeater1.Items[i].FindControl("litMessageId");

                string messageId = litMessageId.Text;
                mySQL = string.Format("delete from messages where messageID = '{0}'", messageId);

                SqlCommand cmdDelete = new SqlCommand(mySQL, connDelete);
                cmdDelete.ExecuteNonQuery();




                // Continue your code here
            }
            else
            {

            }
        }
            if (BindNeeded)
            {
                Repeater1.DataBind();
            }
            else
            {
                Response.Redirect("Messages.aspx");
            }

    }
        catch
    {
        Response.Redirect("Messages.aspx");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

There's something wrong with your code, at this line:

```
mysql = "delete from messages where messageID = '" + CheckBox1.Checked + "'";
```

It should be:

```
mysql = "delete from messages where messageID = '" + ((YourClass)Repeater1.Items[i].DataItem).messageID + "'";
```

And you should use [SqlParameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.aspx) instead of concatenating the String.

Besides, SqlCommand was not executed, you should add this line:

```
cmdDel.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

And you must reload data after deleting message.

Besides, you should initialize SqlConnection Object out of the for loop, and use   SqlTransaction to manage the transaction.

```
 using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=19-20\\sqlexpress;" + "Initial Catalog = mpsip; Integrated Security = SSPI"))
 {     
    conn.Open();
    SqlCommand cmdDel = conn.CreateCommand();
    SqlTransaction transaction = conn.BeginTransaction("MyTransaction");
    cmdDel.Connection = conn;
    cmdDel.Transaction = transaction;
    try {
        for (int i = 0; i < Repeater1.Items.Count; i++)
        { 
         //This assumes data type of messageID is integer, change (int) to the right type
         cmdDel.CommandText = "delete from messages where messageID = '" + ((int)((DataRow)Repeater1.Items[i].DataItem)["messageID"]) + "'";
         cmdDel.ExecuteNonQuery();

         // Continue your code here

         }
         transaction.Commit();
         //TODO: reload data here and binding to Repeater
    }
    catch(Exception ex) {
        try {
            transaction.Rollback();
        }
        catch(Exception ex1) {
            //TODO: write log
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot for the answer! im going to try it now.

Comment: hi i tried your answer but there are some errors which i do not understand. can u help me look at them? thank you so much =)

Comment: @user1550383: what error? I've just edited the answer, pls check.

Comment: @thinkbk i posted the errors on the question. thank you so much for replying so quickly.

Comment: error at 'messageID' , (exception e) and transaction.rollback.

Having same errors after using the edited codes.

Comment: @user1550383: I've just updated, can you try again? Besides, can you post the source code of Messages class?

Comment: @thinkbk ok i have posted the source codes. I have tried the updated codes. the errors are still the same. =(

Comment: @user1550383: pls try again, I updated my code, at least the compile error should be eliminated now.

Comment: @thinkbk thanks solve all but one of the errors

a local variable named 'e' cannot be declared in this scope because it would give a different meaning to 'e', which is already used in a 'parent or current' scope to denote something else

Comment: @user1550383: sorry for my mistake, pls update and try again.

Comment: @thinkbk dont need to appologise sir. =) i can run the program now. but the delete button still does not work. =(

Comment: @user1550383: I added the type conversion for messageID field, pls try again.

Comment: @thinkbk i am using Nvarchar(50) as my data type. so i changed to string for the type conversion. But the button still does not work

Comment: @thinkbk i have changed my button codes please take a look at them.

Comment: @user1550383: can you write down the cmdDel.CommandText value into log and post it?

Comment: @thinkbk cmdDel.CommandText = "delete from messages where messageID = '" + ((String)((DataRow)Repeater1.Items[i].DataItem)["messageID"]) + "'";

Comment: @user1550383: I mean: the run-time value of cmdDel.CommandText. Something likes: Debug.Write(cmdDel.CommandText) after setting value for it.

Comment: @thinkbk the value of dataItem is null only the count is working. Which is the count for number of rows.